# homomorphism of permutations

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, permutation-cycles

I need to find the kernel and image of the following group homomorphism:

$$\varphi:\mathbb Z\to S_7, n\mapsto \sigma^n,$$

where $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\3&4&5&6&7&2&1\end{pmatrix}$.

I already proved that φ is homomorphism. I don't really know where to start with finding them and could use some help in what to use.

Comment: I guess some people can read this post, but on my screen much of it is displaying as gibberish.

Comment: can you explain? I mean, sure, there's a different language involved, but the mathematics in here are preety straight forward.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: I understand what you are asking but permutations don't have kernels and images. You need to find the kernel and image of the homomorphisms $\varphi$, not the permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is just all the elements you can actually reach using your map $\varphi$. Since those are all of the form $\sigma^n$, and $\sigma$ has finite order (given that it's an element of a finite group), you can just list all of them. For concise notation, you can find the smallest positive $n$ for which $\sigma^n=\mathrm{id}$ and write $\operatorname{Im}(\varphi)=\{\sigma^0,\dots,\sigma^{n-1}\}$. This is because starting at $n$, the permutations will repeat.

For the kernel, the work you did for the image makes it so you're almost done. The kernel is made up of those $n\in\mathbb Z$ sent to $\mathrm{id}$. That's exactly the integer multiples of the $n$ from before (the order of $\sigma$). In fact, a nice definition of the order of an element $g\in G$ of any group $G$ is the generator of the kernel of the homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to G, 1\mapsto g$.

Comment: I preety much understood what to do with the image, but I still can wrap my head around the kernel. How do I know there arent any other n∈Z that sent to id in φ except the order of the permutation?

Comment: @OriYehuda if $\sigma^n = 1$ then write $n = qd + r$ where $d$ is the order of $\sigma$ and $r < d$. Then $\sigma^n = \sigma^r = 1$ and since $d$ is minimal with this property, we must have $r = 0$.